# C++ best practices for running other programs from within 'main'

Tags: c++, class, program-entry-point, error-checking

So I have a short program that has to run a few other programs and wait for them to complete.

Currently I am doing this in my main method like this:

```
// Connect to the service
cout << "Starting the service..." << endl;
status = system((SCRIPT_DIR + "/my_service").c_str());
if (WIFEXITED(status)) {
    cout << "Started service successfully" << endl;
} else {
    cerr << "Failed to start the service." << endl;
    return (EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

It looks kind of gross in my main as I have to do it multiple times; is this where this should be done? or should I break it out into a class or function so I don't have all of this error checking in main?

Any other advice is welcome as well!

Comment: Why not put it in a function then?

Comment: Wrap it up in a function.

Comment: and just return the status from my function and check it in main?

Comment: exception is a possibility.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid my main just having 1000 if checks, this might just be how it is though? I'm not experienced at all by the way

Comment: Have a Look at the Poco C++ Library, it provides a nice Class for that, i.e. Poco::Process .. you can simply call a non blocking launch(...) method in that and wait for results from std::out and exit codes with a blocking wait() method. It also provides a ready() function which you could Poll in a statemachine..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A synchronous way would be to start the service within a blocking function and return the exit value. One by one you start the services and wait for them to finish.

Asynchronously:

All the services can be ran in parallel. You may start threads and join them. So when they finish you retrieve exit values.

Alternatively, you can fork() and use pipes in order to let the father give commands to the various children (start different programs)

Comment: Yep, thank you. It needs to complete before the rest of the code continues so I will put it in a function and check the exit value!

Answer (score 0):

You could create a thread for each 'other program' you want to run. However, this may only work if the job of each 'other program' is independent of results or variables of the other 'other programs'